# sqlite file creation

Tags: sqlite

I know this is the stupid question but i am so confused so please help me.
The question is when i use sqlite command line and make a database.

```
SQLite version 3.6.22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> sqlite3 mydata.db
   ---> (now i terminate it using ;)
```

And now i craete tables and use .output filename and then select * from tb(table)
The file craeted nowhere!! 
So please let me know where file craeted.
Or any other method to craete sqlite database file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with this? It perfectly works and both `mydatabase.db` and `foo_contents.txt` exist.

```
C:\Users\··\Desktop>sqlite mydatabase.db
SQLite version 3.7.6.3
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table foo(bar text);
sqlite> begin transaction; insert into foo(bar) select 'a' union all select 'b';
sqlite> end transaction;
sqlite> .output '.\foo_contents.txt'
sqlite> select * from foo;
sqlite> .output stdout
sqlite> .q

C:\Users\··\Desktop>
```

Comment: Actually my floder c:\user\pc\appdata was hidden and file are founded in this folder.Can u tell me how can i change the path so that file will appear on desktop.

Comment: @sunny: Use `.output 'C:\users\your_user_name\Desktop\foo.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your trouble...

```
fpuga@ELNATH:/tmp$ sqlite3 database.sqlite
SQLite version 3.7.4
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /tmp/database.sqlite                                      
sqlite> .exit
fpuga@ELNATH:/tmp$ ls *.sqlite 
database.sqlite
```